# Unable to verify UPPAAL properties

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, deadlock, verification, uppaal

I am verifying a very small model. But I receive the memory exhaust message. I changed the model several times but having same problem.
I thought that problem would be due to using a user defined function or using the select option to get the random number. Then I changed the model and didn't call the function nor used the Selection option but still....
I am wondering either it's UPPAAL's issue or in my model. There is no error other than memory exhaust. Once the value of "r1" and "r2" are changed after that ctl property doesn't work.
[image: change the address]
CTL works for all values of r1 and r2 before the increment.

Answer (score 0):

The model increments several variables (r1, r2 and cntr): if there is no upper bound for them (and it seems there is not, but I cannot see all the functions), then the state space is going to be huge (all values multiplied times the number of locations, times clock zones) and thus exhaust all the memory.

Either make those variables bounded (do not allow increments passed some value), or declare them as meta (don't do it if you do not understand the consequences).

Comment: r1 and r2 are used to run the clock in between the range. When clock approaches r2 then I assign some random numbers to address (using function assign()).  The value of r1 and r2 is only for iteration purpose. I don't want to save past values. How can I show you complete model. Please me some link I will share detail model.